# How to check both list has same values and same length in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, comparison, unordered

for Example:

```
a = ['yes','no','both']
b = ['no','both','yes']
```

it should return True.

Comment: if you know there aren't any duplicates, then `set(a) == set(b)` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my query .